# Oracle sql, single insert statement, multi columns

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, insert

Few weeks ago I saw an article about oracle sql optimization. There was some way to insert f.e. 200 rows in one `INSERT` statement, but it was not `INSERT ALL` clause
like:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO sales (prod_id, cust_id, time_id, amount)
VALUES (product_id, customer_id, weekly_start_date, sales_sun)
INTO sales (prod_id, cust_id, time_id, amount)
VALUES (product_id, customer_id, weekly_start_date+1, sales_mon)
SELECT product_id, customer_id, weekly_start_date, sales_sun,
sales_mon, sales_tue, sales_wed, sales_thu, sales_fri, sales_sat
FROM sales_input_table;
```

I am pretty sure (99%) it has been done with `USING` Clause in PL/SQL(?). Main problem was to "save" one insert statement and executing it 200 times instead of "saving" 200 inserts and executing every of each of them.

I tried to search in Google but always `INSERT ALL` came up. Anyone have an idea or have similar article about "this"?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post some sample data of your input table and simplified ( say 10 instead of 200) needed result?

Comment: I do not have ANY data. I'm just looking this way. I can handle with inserting but this way from article bothering me for few days.

Comment: Err... USING...   Almost surely you read about the MERGE statement. Do a Google search for "Oracle MERGE" and see if that's what you saw in the article.

Answer (score 0):

I would generate a bunch of numbers and do this in a single `insert`.  This version uses `union all` to handle each of the weekday columns:

```
with n as (
     select level as n
     from dual
     connect by level <= 52
    )
insert into sales (prod_id, cust_id, time_id, amount)
    select product_id, customer_id, weekly_start_date + n.n - 1, sales_sun
    from sales_input_table cross join n
    union all
    select product_id, customer_id, weekly_start_date + n.n - 1, sales_mon
    from sales_input_table cross join n
    . . .
```

Comment: But let's say i have table with 500 rows. Do i need to repeat
Select...
from...
union all...

500 times?

Comment: @MichałM please build an example with some rows and show us the result to achieve, so that answers could better fit your needs

Comment: @MichałM . . . No, you only need 7, one for each day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

What you have seen is (sorry... MAY HAVE BEEN - see my comment to your original question though) the insert into (select ...) syntax. For example, suppose I have a table t, and I want to clone it. I create a table s with the same number, name and data type (and order) of columns at t, and now I want to copy all the data from t to s. The simple way to do that is

```
insert into s (select * from t);
```

What's in parentheses (the subquery) can be a full-blown subquery; for example, I can use a WHERE clause to limit which rows are copied to s; or I can use aggregate functions and GROUP BY in the subquery to insert summaries in s, instead of cloning the data; the only condition is that the number and data type of resulting columns in the subquery must match those of s.